# Let Visual Studio only copy error description

Tags: visual-studio

When I have an error after compiled, I'd like to Google it. I copied the error message like

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E0461   initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue   xxxx    D:\xxx\projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.cpp 30

I only want

> E0461 initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

It is inconvenient to delete other work every time when I just want to Google the error.

What should I do to copy just only one cell from the `Error List` window.

Comment: I'd love to know a solution to this as well.

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround, click the Output tab(bottom of VS, right next to Error List tab), select and copy the error message